# ld: library not found for -lcrypto.1.0.0 on OSX 10.11.6

Tags: macos, openssl, libcrypto

Am facing this problem while building on OSX 10.11.6
Our solution used to build well 10.10 and earlier but with OSX 10.11 facing this issue.
I have installed latest openssl. 
In project.pbxproj I have given absolute path of lib - /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib

Have added this in DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH variables.
Have added this in LDFLAGS too.
Have included /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2h/lib path too.
Still facing this linking error.

I don't have prior experience in mac, just trying to make this build work.
Any help is appreciated, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS in build file worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it adding LIBRARY_PATH variable with the path to the library.

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
```

In my case, I included it on .gitlab-ci.yml, but I guess adding it elsewhere will work.